# Rails, sorcery: can I not hash the password at all?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, sorcery

So, I went into the Sorcery source code and discovered that it already does, without telling anyone, what Devise recommends doing for testing purposes: Set BCrypt stretches to 1.

Woohoo. However, it's still rather painful to create users. Is there a way, with sorcery, to not hash at all when creating a user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a config option for sorcery. In an initializer:

```
config.encryption_algorithm = :none
```

List of default providers here: 
https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery/blob/master/lib/sorcery/model.rb

Config talked about here:
https://codeclimate.com/github/NoamB/sorcery/Sorcery::CryptoProviders

Answer (score 0):

Sorcery allows you to override the encryption provider. Just have a support file that sets `User.custom_encryption_provider = Sorcery::CryptoProviders::SHA1`, or similar.

Make sure that this is only used in tests, obviously. You still want strong bcrypt for production. It might not be a bad idea to have tests that perform user creation with bcrypt still in place, too, so you don't have a disparity between your test and production code.